# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ProgressEvent: {"isTrusted":true}

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i am making a put request from my ionic app to an api :

```
     updateDeviceToken(params):Promise<any>{
        return this.http
          .put(this.endpoint + '/devicetoken',params)
          .toPromise()
          .then((response: any) => response);
      }
```

i am getting this error :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ProgressEvent: {"isTrusted":true}

when i run the app on the web i don't get any error and the PUT request is done correctly
i get this error whenever i run on the emulator or real device

Comment: is your endpoint HTTP or HTTPS? Is the simulator/device Android or iOS?

Comment: i al testing on android simulator ( android studio emulator)

Comment: `http` is it `HttpClient` or `HTTP` (`@ionic-native/http`)? Have you the error on every request from the device or only for this particular request or just PUT requests?

Comment: http is HttpClient , nope tried with post and get same issue , the weird thing is when i run on the web it works i get this only when i run on emulator/real device